# Pylint: Linter pylint is not installed. after installing as extension - VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, linter

I just installed python 3.8.3 and created a file.
a message shows up;

> Linter pylint is not installed. Source: Python (Extension)

I clicked the install button and I have this error message now...

```
$ C:/Python38/python.exe c:\Users\JAEMIN\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.90262\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip install -U py 
lint --user

C:\Python38\python.exe: can't open file 'c:UsersJAEMIN.vscodeextensionsms-python.python-2020.6.90262pythonFilespyvsc-run-isolated.py': [Errno 
2] No such file or directory
```

I searched but nothing seems to work in my case.

What is Linter pylint? and do I need it?

thank you

Comment: Pylint is for static code analysis, and you do not need it to run your Python programs.

Comment: What OS and shell are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should check whether the file 'c:\Users\JAEMIN.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.90262\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py' exists. It's provided by the 'python' extension which you have installed. You can try to reinstall this extension. You'd better remove the 'ms-python.python-2020.6.90262' folder just in case, then install the 'python' extension again.

Second, when you tried to install 'pylint' through command 'pip install pylint', you get the error: 'pip: command not found'. It seems like you haven't created a virtual environment. If you created it, and you activate the environment(Ctrl+Shift+`), you can get pip work. You can refer to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments) page for more information, and this is the recommended method. But you can still choose to use the default global python, but it seems like when you install the python3.8.3 you haven't chosen 'pip' on the first page. So, the system can't find 'pip' command. A few months ago, I remembered although you install python, you still need to install pip manually. You can refer to [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) page to know how to install pip.

Answer (score 0):

Let me directly pickup the documentation of [pylint](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/essential-python-tools/en/latest/linters.html#:%7E:text=Syntax%20errors-,pylint,tool%20for%20linting%20in%20python.)

pylint

> Pylint is a python linter which checks the source code and also acts
> as a bug and quality checker. It has more verification checks and
> options than just PEP8(Python style guide).
>
> This is the most commonly used tool for linting in python.
>
> It includes the following features: Checking the length of each line
> Checking if variable names are well-formed according to the project’s
> coding standard Checking if declared interfaces are truly implemented.

Linter is an optional tool and it is used to check the source code for stylistic errors.

Comment: thanks for explanation. but if I want to install it, what can i do?
if I try to install pylint by "pip install pylint", I get error saying "pip: command not found"

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer described, pylint is code checking tool for stylistic errors. If you want to get rid of the error message, I believe you just need to do `pip install pylint`.

Comment: I tried.. but I get this error message: pip: command not found

Comment: If you're doing it from command line directly, do `python -m pip install pylint`.